# Why parity conserves in fermi transition?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, parity

Beta decay is a weak interaction process and in weak interaction parity doesnot conserve , then why in fermi transition initial and final parties of the nucleus is conserved ?

Comment: [Related, possible duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/605013/44126). It’s not entirely clear what you’re asking here; remember that the parity eigenvalue of an atom changes during parity-conserving electric dipole transitions.

Comment: The more accurate statement is that parity ***may*** be violated in a weak interaction. V-A.

Comment: Maybe you are asking whether a weak interaction is blocked whenever it conserves parity? No.